# Error in root.matrix(crossprod(process)) : matrix is not positive semidefinite

Tags: r, random-forest, naivebayes

I want to extend the `RandomForest` so that each leaf will contain `naivebayes` regression instead of average. In the following, I first tried to use `mob()` for adding `linearModel`. I got the following error:

```
Error in root.matrix(crossprod(process)) :    matrix is not positive semidefinite
```

Here is my code:

```
require (data.table)
require (party)
set.seed(123)

data1 <- read.csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data',header = TRUE)
colnames(data1)<-  c("BuyingPrice","Maintenance","NumDoors","NumPersons","BootSpace","Safety","Condition")

# Split into Train and Validation sets
# Training Set : Validation Set = 70 : 30 (random)
set.seed(100)
train <- sample(nrow(data1), 0.7*nrow(data1), replace = FALSE)
TrainSet <- data1[train,]
ValidSet <- data1[-train,]
summary(TrainSet)
summary(ValidSet)

# Create a Random Forest model with default parameters
model1 <- randomForest(Condition ~ ., data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)
model1

# Fine tuning parameters of Random Forest model
model2 <- randomForest(Condition ~ ., data = TrainSet, ntree = 500, mtry = 6, importance = TRUE)
model2


fmBH <- mob(Condition ~ BuyingPrice +  Maintenance | NumDoors+ NumPersons + BootSpace + Safety ,
            data = TrainSet, model = linearModel)
```

Comment: I see no question marks... Also, your code doesn't really contain anything related to Naive Bayes. So, be sure to make it clear whether you care about understanding the error (as the title suggests) or something related to Naive Bayes.

Comment: Thanks, @Julius Vainora, I asked how to change the model = linearModel to naivebayes and on the way I got error for linear model.

Comment: Hi @Avi, I think you have to adapt the model to your problem. Your target variable is a factor, so you have no regression problem, it is either a classification problem. 
And I don't know if mob is working with multiclassification-problem. See for more details: `vignette("MOB")`
I tried the following and your initial problem is kind of solved: 
`fmBH <- mob(TrainSet$Condition ~ BuyingPrice +  Maintenance | NumDoors+ NumPersons + BootSpace + Safety ,
            data = TrainSet, model = glinearModel, family = binomial())`

Comment: @Avi, I suggest to make it clear in your question. The error comes from the fact that `Condition` is a factor and you are fitting a linear model. As to use Naive Bayes, you need to create this model type, see `model` in `?mob`.

Comment: Thanks both. @floe - I tried your solution it works with 26 warnings I don't know why... I would like to know how can I change the model to naivebayes instead of glinearModel when the target value is not factor?

Comment: I think it is just possible to hand over models of type `StatModel`, I don't know if there is a naiveBays model of class StatModel, sorry.